# Execution failed for task ':zipalignDebug'

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-2.0.0

I am encountering this problem when I run

```
ionic build android
```

I have attached screenshot for more information.

Can someone help me fixing this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had that error once because i was using QR Barcode Scanner. You have to change this in your build.gradle file

```
  lintOptions {
      abortOnError true
  }
```

solution:

```
  lintOptions {
          abortOnError false
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I am not using QA Barcode Scanner. 
Anyway its not working event after I made this change.